# Correct C++ approach to store multi-type data

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, data-storage

Let me consider that I have 4 bytes that describe some real system parameters. Suppose that could be interpreted as float, uint32_t and boolean. The main idea to store and process this variables together. Now I use one class that (very simplified) have array of 4 bytes, functions `float toFloat()`, `uint32_t toInt()`, `bool toBool()` and parameter ID (which specifies storing value type). So I need one function `T getValue()` which will be returning the value of correct type `T`. So my question is: what is the most correct way to do so? Should I use templates, inheritance, its combination or something else?

Comment: `std::variant<float, uint32_t, bool>` might help.

Comment: You cannot return different types from the same function. If you know at compile-time what type you expect, then templates can help, but otherwise there is no way to have "one function `T getvalue()` which will be returning the value of correct type `T`". What would the type of the variable be that you store that value in? It must be known at compile-time. `std::variant` provides a way around that but it's quite verbose.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yes, I understand it, so I have tried to use template. Even I create this objects like a = common<int>(2), b = common<float>(3.14), could I use some mechanism to get value without type pointing? Like a.getValue() and not b<float>.getValue().

Comment: @Stanislav What type would `x = a.getValue()` have? The compiler has to decide on **one** type at compile-time. If you can't tell the compiler the type at compile-time, you won't be able to compile your program. If you actually do know the type at compile-time and just want to avoid the typing, implicit conversions may help (but you should generally stay clear of them).

Comment: Hm... Could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve? Maybe there's a better approach at some higher level.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Could I write function 'T getValue()' that will be used type T based on some inner variable like 'typedef T value_type'? As I understand this type T will be known at compile-time, if I create variables a and b somewhere, right?

Comment: @Aconcagua I have a lot of real-system parameters with certain "ID-names" which are described by different types. I know which type has variable with any ID. I want to store it in one common container (e.g. vector) and process it in one foreach loop. Now I could store type ID inside class and process it like (if var.type = 1 then var.toFloat). So my interested, if could I make it only with inner class possibilities.

Comment: @Stanislav Looping over variables of different types directly is impossible (I assume you mean that `getValue` would return different types in different loop iterations). `std::variant` + `std::visit` can get you there though. In any case, please add code demonstrating how you intend to use this.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
std::variant<float, uint32_t, bool> bytes(3.1415);
```

Comment: `variant` is probably what OP should use, but I'm not sure if that is what they actually mean. It says "I have 4 bytes (...) that could be interpreted as float, uint32_t and boolean" - so the same four bytes could be interpreted as different things? (which maybe could just be a template method in a class).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is a good way to convert bytes to variables, but my question is not only about converting. I want to get storing value only based on value type storing with this value. E.g. I have temperature (float), number of measurements (uin32_t) and sensor's state (bool). Than I want to get three variables for every case and get that values without using a direct pointing on this type like it supposed in 'std::variant'

Comment: @Stanislav You should ask that as a new question then.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a perfect usecase for unions. The only thing amiss is that in a union you don't know which value type was stored. You could either attach the type information, for example allowing access to the union member with an accessor setting the type up, or if you have any other mean to know the type you could use that.

Comment: Paul Evans's answer is better.

Comment: @Oblivion It's 2019, you don't want to be using `union` in C++.

Comment: @PaulEvans of course nobody wants to use union. But when s newbie comes across a legacy code it's good to have an idea what that's for.

Comment: @Oblivion So as a bad example? Probably better to teach newbies the right way to start them off.

Comment: @PaulEvans exactly and also for those of us who have to maintain old codes. The truth is unions will be around for some while. and for a new code union IMO is a mistake

Comment: @Oblivion [CppCon 2017: Scott Schurr “Type Punning in C++17: Avoiding Pun-defined Behavior”](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/77nael/cppcon_2017_scott_schurr_type_punning_in_c17/)

Comment: This use case has nothing to do with type punning.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays must have unique datatypes, otherwise you must build a parallel array structure using multiple arrays in conjunction.